# How to disable Surface Pro 4 touchscreen with a script?

Tags: windows, powershell, switch-statement, touchscreen

I was looking for few days ago how to toggle ON/OFF my Surface Pro 4 touchscreen easily.
After some researches here is my script:

https://github.com/mortalink/ON-OFFSurfacePro4Touchscreen

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I just wanted to help people looking for this answer :)